# Completed tensor product of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

According to [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AMU) definition of completed tensor product, it is stated that $\lim M\otimes_RN/(M_\mu\otimes R+R\otimes N_\nu)=\lim M/M_\mu\otimes N/N_\nu$. Why these two inverse limit are equal? I don't think $M\otimes_RN/(M_\mu\otimes R+R\otimes N_\nu)\cong M/M_\mu\otimes N/N_\nu$ holds in general. Is it also true that $M\hat{\otimes}N/M_\mu\hat{\otimes} N_\nu\cong M/M_\mu\otimes N/N_\nu$?

Comment: The isomorphism $(M\otimes_RN)/(M_\mu\otimes N+M\otimes N_\nu)\cong(M/M_\mu)\otimes_R(N/N_\nu)$ holds in general.